# Tensor products over monoids : Element structure

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, monoid

Let $A$ be a (commutative) monoid. Let $M$ be a right $A$-set and let $N$ be a left $A$-set. Then we can construct the tensor product $M \otimes_A N$, which is a set (of even $A$-set when $A$ is commutative) constructed from $M \times N$ by modding out the equivalence relation $\sim$ generated by $(ma,n) \sim (m,an)$. Thus, every element of $M \otimes_A N$ has the form $m \otimes n := [(m,n)]$.

**Question.** Is there an easy criterion how to decide $m \otimes n = m' \otimes n'$?

In other words, how to describe $\sim$ explicitly? It is easy when $A$ is a group, but I'm interested in more general (commutative) monoids.

Comment: What do you have in mind for the case when $A$ is a group?

Comment: Consider the relation $\sim'$ defined by $(m,n) \sim' (m',n')$ iff $m'=ma$, $n=n'a$ for some $a \in A$. This is transitive and reflexive. If $A$ is a group, then it is also symmetric, and hence equal to $\sim$.